# Включение одного Spring-приложения в состав другого

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Есть два независимых web-приложения. Первое web-приложение: на Spring-boot, с авторизацией через spring-security, со своей бизнес-логикой. И второе web-приложение: на Spring (Spring MVC), без авторизации, со своей бизнес-логикой.

Задача: встроить второе приложение в первое, чтобы второе отображалось на одной из страниц первого (в iframe например), чтобы при этом второе не было доступно без авторизации в первом. В идеале подключать второе приложение в виде war/jar или зависимости.

Возможно ли такое провернуть? Если да, то как это сделать или хотябы в какую сторону копать?